# Writing accurate <th> for accessible <table>

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I am following the [UN's accessibility guidelines](http://www.un.org/webaccessibility/3_text/33_datatables.shtml) to write accessible table.

I have this table. I made what  *-I think-* should be a `<th>` **bold**.

[image: Table]

This is the HTML:

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>1991</th>
            <th>1995</th>
            <th>2000</th>
            <th>2002</th>
            <th>2007</th>
        </tr>
    </htead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Indicator 1</th>
            <td>3.0</td>
            <td>11.0</td>
            <td>7.8</td>
            <td>4.0</td>
            <td>4.7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Indicator 2</th>
            <td>9.0</td>
            <td>23.4</td>
            <td>19.5</td>
            <td>9.4</td>
            <td>9.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Indicator 3</th>
            <td>18.7</td>
            <td>32.0</td>
            <td>30.0</td>
            <td>20.1</td>
            <td>21.8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I am not sure it is accurate. I think this makes more sense:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th id="year">Year</th>
            <td headers="year" id="year-1991">1991</td>
            <td headers="year" id="year-1995">1995</td>
            <td headers="year" id="year-2000">2000</td>
            <td headers="year" id="year-2002">2002</td>
            <td headers="year" id="year-2007">2007</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="indicator-1">Indicator 1</th>
            <td headers="indicator-1 year-1991">3.0</td>
            <td headers="indicator-1 year-1995">11.0</td>
            <td headers="indicator-1 year-2000">7.8</td>
            <td headers="indicator-1 year-2002">4.0</td>
            <td headers="indicator-1 year-2007">4.7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="indicator-2">Indicator 2</th>
            <td headers="indicator-2 year-1991">9.0</td>
            <td headers="indicator-2 year-1995">23.4</td>
            <td headers="indicator-2 year-2000">19.5</td>
            <td headers="indicator-2 year-2002">9.4</td>
            <td headers="indicator-2 year-2007">9.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="indicator-3">Indicator 3</th>
            <td headers="indicator-3 year-1991">18.7</td>
            <td headers="indicator-3 year-1995">32.0</td>
            <td headers="indicator-3 year-2000">30.0</td>
            <td headers="indicator-3 year-2002">20.1</td>
            <td headers="indicator-3 year-2007">21.8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What do you think? Does anyone have experience with tables and accessibility? Please provide references if possible. Thanks.

Note: I am aware of the `summary` attribute but I removed it here for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a table with a simple structure like this, your markup (the first, simple version)  is sufficient for accessibility. A table with similar structure appears in HTML and XHTML Techniques for WCAG 2.0, item [Using table markup to present tabular information](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/html.html#H51), with no extra markup, just `th` for header cells.

Special techniques may be need for structurally more complicated tables.

However, a data table should normally have a `caption` element for accessibility and usability. It helps the user get key information about the table as a whole. Instead of a caption, a heading or just text before the table could be used for the purpose, but they do not associate with the table (at the markup level) the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What do you think of use the `scope` attribute for the rows (as I provided as an answer)? Does it add any value or it's unnecessary? Thanks again

Comment: I don’t think the `scope` attributes improve accessibility in this simple case, but of course they are correct and *could* conceivably help some user agents. But they are really meant to be used in more complicated cases.

Comment: I think adding `scope` attributes when there is more than one axis for the headings is prudent.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using the `scope` attribute makes more sense:

```
<table width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">1991</th>
        <th scope="col">1995</th>
        <th scope="col">2000</th>
        <th scope="col">2002</th>
        <th scope="col">2007</th>
    </tr>
</htead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Indicator 1</th>
        <td>3.0</td>
        <td>11.0</td>
        <td>7.8</td>
        <td>4.0</td>
        <td>4.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Indicator 2</th>
        <td>9.0</td>
        <td>23.4</td>
        <td>19.5</td>
        <td>9.4</td>
        <td>9.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Indicator 3</th>
        <td>18.7</td>
        <td>32.0</td>
        <td>30.0</td>
        <td>20.1</td>
        <td>21.8</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Reference: [Use the th element to specify row and column headers in data tables | 456 Berea St](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200910/use_the_th_element_to_specify_row_and_column_headers_in_data_tables/)

Comment: I always specify the `scope` as a means of common practice, and is required where I work, unless the table is more complex thus `headers` are needed. In your code above `<th scope="col">Year</th>` should be `<th scope="row">Year</th>`